# Having conflicts when update UIButton image within UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have an app with some posts placed at an UITableView. Each post have a favorite button and I need to change its image when the user clicks on it. Here are the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if(cell == nil){
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNib" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSDictionary *post = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.likeButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(clickedOnLike:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And on click handler:

```
-(IBAction)clickedOnLike:(id)sender
{

int tag = buttonSender.tag;
NSDictionary *post = [posts objectAtIndex:tag];

if( ![self likedAlready:post] ){

    //set liked on this view...

    //update view
    NSLog(@"button: %@",buttonSender);
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //send like to server...
  }
}
```

At this point, everything is going alright. The problem is, after click a button, update the view and scroll to other cells, the other buttons views I never clicked are updated too. For example, when I click a button at indexPath 1, the ones at 5 and 9 change their images automatically. This is a mistery to me, since I call the action sender directly and update only it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Since the cells are reused, the "addTarget" calls remain still, I think (probably they're stacking). Maybe you should remove actions for control events in the beginning of the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reusable cell do it: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

U need to deal manually with things like this.

U can invoke manually to your `clickedOnLike:` method from the `CellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Try to maintain inside your modal (from your MVC development architecture), and access there from the  `CellForRowAtIndexPath:`

That will solve your problem :)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, set the default image of your button, then change it if its a favorite. The rows tend to get cached so always set your data to what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the problem is because the view is recycled for everyline, and in the recycled copy the button may have had its picture changed to the new one.
you need to keep somewhere in memory the status of the post, and on the cellForRowAtIndexpath set the correct image for the button every time the row is rendered.

Alternatively, if you have a very small number of posts, just eliminate recycling by doing

static NSString *identifier = nil;